# How to get common column names from two SQL Server tables on different servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `a.table` in database b, which resides on server c.

I have another table named `d.table` in database e, which resides on server f .

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('Tempdb..#A') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #A

SELECT * 
INTO #A 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 10 * 
     FROM c.b.a.table) AS V

IF OBJECT_ID ('Tempdb..#B') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #B

SELECT * 
INTO #B 
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 10 * 
     FROM f.e.d.table) AS Z

SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '#A'

INTERSECT

SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '#B'
```

How do I write a query to get common column from two tables. had they been residing in the same server, it would have been a different ask, which i could have completed.

Comment: Linked server is the only option I can think of if you want to use one sql statement to do it. Otherwise use Excel (get the results from each server and copy/paste to a work sheet).

Answer (score 1):

Use a linked server and information schema

```
SELECT
    *
FROM [LinkedServer].[DataBase].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS]
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```